# Query to Skip the first Delimiter and select the second Delimiter In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

I am trying to run a query where

```
,replace(b.[X.Logs],' ','.') as 'logs'
,CT2 as 
(
  Select *
    , CHARINDEX('Diagnostics',[logs]) as 'DiagBGN1'
    , CHARINDEX('.',[logs],CHARINDEX('Diagnostics',[logs])) as 'DiagEND1'
  From CT1
)
,CT3 as
(
  Select * 
    ,SUBSTRING([logs],[EPSABGN1]+1,[EPSAEND1]-[EPSABGN1]-1) as 'EPSA_CODE'
  From CT2
)
```

I would like the Code to Skip the first `.` and select the next preceding `.` as the delimiter.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: parse em all then skip em once you've deserialized

Comment: The Logs suggest some thing similar 1)Diagnostics.Passed.hardware 2.Diagnostics.failed.Hardware. I would like to ignore the . Post Diagnostics keyword.

Comment: How do you parse them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like below:

```
declare @S varchar(200) = 'Diagnostics.Passed.hardware';
select substring(@s, charindex('.', @S)+1, len(@s));
```

CharIndex will provide the 'index' of the first '.' and then use it to get substring from the string. This will 'ignore' the word "Diagnostics." from the string.

Comment: But this will become static. I would like keep this dynamic.

Comment: the variable @s is an example. you can replace @s with the actual column name from table. Use the substring(@s, charindex('.', @S)+1, len(@s)) and replace it with the field you are selecting.